# passing information from html to python script

Tags: python, html

I have a form that I made via html where I enter a longitude and latitude and then submit this information.  Now I want the latitude and longitude that I entered on the html form to be used in called a python script.  Each element in the form is a command line argument in called the python script:

> ./python.py

How do I call the python script python.py with the appropriate arguments as specified above based on the latitude and longitude information I submitted in a form on the website.  Here is a snippet of the html code.

```
<center>Please Enter a Longitude and Latitude of the point where you want to look     at</center>
<center>(Longitudes West and Latitudes South should be entered as negative numbers i.e 170W is -170).</center>
<br></br>
<form>
<center>
Longitude: <br>
<input type="text" name="Longitude" />
<br>
Latitude: <br>
<input type="text" name="Latitude" />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I add here to have the html file call ./python.py  upon hitting the submit button?

Comment: you need to encode url

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: can you give the website link??

Comment: I don't have an official link for it yet.  The link is now file:///home/jsnyder/Desktop/pydap/website.html?Longitude=&Latitude=&submit=Submit

Comment: use a server then encode url, uring urllib2 and urllib module

Comment: where do I encode this?  in the python script or the html script?

Comment: what you are tying to achive???

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a Python web server. A simple way to do this is by installing the Flask library. For example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/runscript', methods=['POST'])
def my_script():
    lat = request.form.get('lat')
    lon = request.form.get('lon')
    return "You submitted: lat=%s long=%s" % (lat,lon)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now run the web server from the command line:

```
$ python myscript.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

You can submit `POST` requests to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/runscript` to see the result. I just submitted a request from the command line using `curl`:

```
$ curl -X POST --data "lat=1&lon=2" http://127.0.0.1:5000/runscript
You submitted: lat=1 long=2
```

Comment: This looks good but how does it link up with the scripts I already have including python.py and the html script that I posted.  I am fairly new to this and need a step by step explanation of how to tie in what you wrote here to link the html script that I wrote here to the python script python.py?